# Tuple unpacking to new and existing variables in a statically typed language with type inference

Tags: compiler-construction, language-design, iterable-unpacking

Consider a tuple of types integer, float, string:

```
(int, float, string) x = (2, 4.2, "string")
```

Unpacking the values from the tuples can be achieved with type inference or pre defining the types.

```
(int, float, string) (arg1, arg2, arg3) = x
//or
(arg4, arg5, arg6) = x
```

The issue is that by including the type modifiers it is telling the compiler that all variables within the tuple extraction are new and thus must be declared with the corresponding types. However, if the programmer wants to combine a mix of existing variables and new variables in the tuple extraction, it means that they can no longer use the type modifiers because this would suggest to the compiler that they are creating new variables. But without using type modifiers type inference will give the programmer a type that they may not necessarily want. e.g:

```
int arg1 = 0
(int, float, string) (arg1, arg2, arg3) = x //ERROR: arg1 already declared

(arg1, arg5, arg6) = x //Fine: but doesn't allow the programmer to explicitly declare the types they want
```

Are there any programming languages that have this confliction issue within tuple unpacking and if so how do they solve them?

Comment: I'm assuming the language you're trying to construct is dynamically-typed, since this would be a non-problem for a statically-typed language?

Comment: Python deals with this by not having variable declarations. Type hints can be applied in most places, regardless of if a variable they're being applied to is "new" or not.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Statically typed actually. I think this problem is fairly easily solved in a dynamically typed as python shows. How could this be achieved in a statically typed language?

Comment: If the language is statically typed, the type of `x` is known, so other than for superfluous documentation purposes, you wouldn't need to add types to the unpacking line.

Comment: @Carcigenicate but what if one wanted to define a type so that they can unpack a different but compatible type: e.g. (float, float, string) (arg1, arg2, arg3) = x, thus arg1 gets converted from a int to a float?

Comment: The problem seems more related to variable declaration than to strict or dynamic typing. Lua, a dynamic language, would *not* allow this: ```local obj = {x=1}; local obj.x, y, z = ... some function returning multiple values```;  we can't treat ```obj.x``` as a local; the solution would be to previously declare y and z also: ```local y, z; obj.x, y, z =  ...```